# Working With Mins and Maxes - Heapq Appropriate?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a scheduling algorithm where I compare the min and the max of a list of priority/task tuples, do some operations on them that change their priority, then re-insert them into the list and have the list update appropriately. Would heapq be the best data structure for this? How would I make the initial comparisons (which would basically be determining if the priority values were far enough apart to need further operation; if not the function would cease) without popping? Once the comparisons were made, how would I take the max along with the min, since heapq is designed for popping the min only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`heapq` provides only a min-heap—that is, you can pop the `min` value in O(log N) time, but not the `max` value.

If you want a double-sided data structure similar to `heapq`, there are a few basic options.

First, what's the problem with a regular min heap? It's not just the API; finding the max value takes `O(n)` time instead of `O(1)` time, and therefore popping it takes `O(n)` instead of `O(log n)`, and that's the key thing you want to improve.

A simple hack involves keeping two heaps, one with the normal values, one with the normal values decorated so they sort backward. Here's the implementation in pseudocode:

```
def push(self, value):
    insert into both normal and reversed heaps
def minpop(self):
    check that the min value of normal hasn't reached the min value of reversed
    pop and return the min value of normal
def maxpop(self):
    check that the min value of reversed hasn't reached the min value of normal
    pop and return the min value of reversed
```

At first glance, it seems like the worst-case behavior for every operation ought to be exactly twice that of a minheap, but that's not true. In particular, the worst-case space is the number of elements ever inserted, which can be much higher than twice the number inserted - the number deleted. (For example, if you've inserted 1000 items and deleted 100, 900 >> 200.)

There are many use cases for which this will not work, and it should be obvious if it won't work in your use case. But when it *is* appropriate, it's dead-simple.

If it *isn't* appropriate, you can use a real min-max heap. This basically just interleaves the `normal` and `reversed` versions of a min heap into a single structure, and makes it easy to do the right thing (instead of leaving values behind) in the "check" case above.

But, if you want symmetric performance for a double-ended priority queue, you can't actually do any better than a balanced tree or a skiplist. (Well, not for general purpose. If you have specific behavior characteristics, that may not be true.) And there are a lot more implementations of AVL trees, red-black trees, and skiplists out there than min-max binary heaps. So, search PyPI and the ActiveState recipes for "balanced tree", "red-black tree", "AVL tree", "skiplist", etc., and you'll find things like [`bintrees`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/0.3.0) and [`skiplist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/skiplist/0.1.0), which should all work.

However, I'd recommend [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/1.3.4). It uses a special hybrid of a balanced tree and an array rather than a well-studied data structure, which at first glance might make you think it's less trustworthy. However, I believe it gets a lot more use and real-world testing than any of the competing modules, and it's also been optimized pretty heavily. (When you're dealing with `A * log Bn + C` performance, changing `A` or `C` usually has a lot more impact than changing `B`.) It's also got a nice interface—actually, a few of them. If you use `blist.sortedlist`, you can just do `sl[0]`, `sl[-1]`, `sl.pop(0)`, `sl.pop(-1)`, and `sl.add(x)`, pretty much exactly as you'd expect.

So, your code would look something like this (if I understand your English description):

```
class MyQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sl = blist.sortedlist(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    def add(self, priority, task):
        self.sl.add((priority, task))
    def step(self):
        if self.sl[-1][0] - self.sl[0][0] < MyQueue.EPSILON:
            return
        minprio, mintask = self.sl.pop(0)
        maxprio, maxtask = self.sl.pop(-1)
        newminprio, newmaxprio = recalc_priorities(minprio, maxprio)
        self.add(newminprio, mintask)
        self.add(newmaxprio, maxtask)
```

The problem with any of these methods is that the worst case for peeking both sides is `O(log N)` rather than `O(1)`. But there's an easy way around this, if these are the only operations you need: Just keep those values cached:

```
class MyQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sl = blist.sortedlist(key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        self.minprio, self.maxprio = None, None
    def add(self, priority, task):
        self.sl.add((priority, task))
        if prio < self.minprio: self.minprio = prio
        elif prio > self.maxprio: self.maxprio = prio
    def step(self):
        if self.maxprio - self.minprio < MyQueue.EPSILON:
            return
        minprio, mintask = self.sl.pop(0)
        maxprio, maxtask = self.sl.pop(-1)
        newminprio, newmaxprio = recalc_priorities(minprio, maxprio)
        self.add(newminprio, mintask)
        self.add(newmaxprio, maxtask)
        self.minprio, self.maxprio = sl[0][0], sl[-1][0]
```

This makes the fast path through `step` `O(1)` instead of `O(log n)`, and it leaves all existing `O(log n)` operations still `O(log n)`.

Also see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation) for a discussion of other kinds of heaps that can replace binary heaps that might be relevant here.

One last note, which igorrs's comments reminded me of:

There are a variety of different data structures that will get you the same worst-case algorithmic complexity here. Sometimes, anything that avoids `O(n)` is good enough, so you should just go with the simplest implementation and be done with it. But sometimes (especially with many operations but small `n`, or with atypical data), the constant factor, the best case, etc. can make a huge difference. In that case, the right thing to do is build multiple implementations and test with real data, and see what's fastest.

Comment: +1 for posting actual code that solves the problem under the given constraints.

Comment: I'm late to the party but I just want to point out that a heapq can be converted into a max-heap by simply negating the priority.

Comment: @st0le: If you read beyond the first line, that's already pretty obvious from the answer. The OP's problem is that he wants a double-sided heap, and the hard part is pairing a minheap and maxheap to get that, not just building a maxheap.

Comment: @abarnert, Although, not an ideal solution. Wikipedia mentions the first method as keeping two separate heaps one for min, one for max. I was merely suggesting that method. The heavy lifting can be done by heapq at the cost of space.

Comment: @st0le: Have you read the answer you're commenting on? The start of the answer describes the two-heaps solution, explains why it's simple, and reviews the space costs, before moving on to alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are considering a heap, I can assume that your expectations (with `n` being the total number of elements) are:

1. Find the smallest key and the biggest key in `O(1)` time.
2. Reinsert (with changed keys) the element with the smallest key and the element with the biggest key, in `O(log(n))` time.

This can be accomplished with a [min-max heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap). Unfortunately, I don't think this is available in Python's standard library.

If you relax the first requirement, any balanced tree (red-black, for example) will do the trick, with `O(log(n))` time for all of the desired operations.

Python's standard library also does not provide any balanced tree, so you would have to roll your own or look for an implementation.

Comment: A min-max heap can't be as efficient as a min heap in both directions, just one or the other, which means it's effectively as good as a balanced tree (unless you often want to check the min value without popping), so your original answer was good enough.

Comment: With a min-max heap, the smallest and the biggest keys can be found in `O(1)`. This is important, because @user1427661 **does not want to pop every time** (the question talks about comparing the two keys and doing nothing in some situations).

Comment: Yes, but, say, a red-black tree and a cache of the top and bottom preserves the same performance guarantees. The key here is that he wants to peek both sides, and will not change anything if he doesn't immediately pop, except to insert new values. So, you can just update the cache on pop and insert, and giving you `O(1)` peeks with no performance impact. (Unless I'm not understanding his entire use case.) The most important thing you don't get from a peek-caching tree is `heappushpop`, but you also don't get that (on both sides) with a min-max heap.

Comment: I agree that you can keep an updated cache without any impact in the asymptotic behavior, even if you're just using the tree (without any control over its internals). It's a less elegant solution, but it gives you the same guarantees.
Now, regarding `heappushpop`: for the described use case, I don't think that having this operation available would improve the performance guarantees, because there's no pop of a single element, and pops never happen without previous analysis of both the minimum and the maximum.

Comment: That's exactly my point: The only place a cached-tree is (asymptotically) less efficient is if you need `heappushpop`, and the OP doesn't need it. As for elegance… well, maybe, but even so, if you can get the same or better performance with an already-written, well-designed, and heavily-tested library instead of trying to implement a data structure and algorithms from scratch, that's probably more important for most use cases.